# How to set entire mapping to read only in NHibernate 3.2 mapping-by-code?

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

I'm just getting up to speed with NHibernate 3.2 and its "mapping by code" feature, and migrating our Fluent mapping over to it.
Is there an equivalent of the fluent "ReadOnly();" function, to make the entire mapping read only?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Mutable(false) in the mapping.

Read this post for corresponding hbm file mapping from where I could infer this.

http://davybrion.com/blog/2007/08/read-only-data-in-nhibernate/

Answer (score 6):

Use PropertyMapper action to define access style:

```
public class EntityMapping : ClassMapping<Entity>
{
     public EntityMapping()
     {
         Id(m => m.Id, map => map.Generator(Generators.HighLow));
         Property(m => m.Name, map => map.Access(Accessor.ReadOnly));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for this in fluent you are looking for ReadOnly() as below:

```
public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo> {

    public FooMap() {
        Schema("bar");
        Table("foo");
        LazyLoad();

        ReadOnly();

        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.ID, "ID")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Year, "Year");
        Map(x => x.FirstField).Column("FirstField").Length(1);
    }
}
```